# set --no-browser from jupyter_notebook_config.py in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I would like to always start 'jupyter lab' with the --no-browser option.  I realize I could create an alias, but my question is:  How can I change `jupyter_notebook_config.py` to specify that I want that option

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the [answer by Robert Lugg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174790/1056268).

It might be the case that your version of `JupyterLab` expects configuration in a different file, for example, `.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.py`. Then

```
jupyter server --generate-config
```

will generate the file `.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.py`, which you can then edit setting

```
c.ServerApp.open_browser = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it documented here:
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

The option is `NotebookApp.open_browser`
, so the entry in `jupyter_notebook_config.py` would be:

```
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```